# Magento 2 How find css in theme for changes and apply also in pub/static

Tags: magento2, css

I want to apply **`css`** in ***ced_vpanel.css*** file which is located in **`pub/static`.**

> `/pub/static/frontend/Ced/ced_2k18/en_US/Ced_CsMarketplace/css/ced/csmarketplace/ced_vpanel.css`

want changes in css file according to my requirement

how to find css in theme for changes and apply also in pub/static  ?

Comment: Please post the full css file path....We cannot override files in pub/static folder...It is dynamically created when we run contend:deploy command.We have to override via specific module.

Comment: @Ranganathan Path is : /pub/static/frontend/Ced/ced_2k18/en_US/Ced_CsMarketplace/css/ced/csmarketplace/ced_vpanel.css. I want to change css in this file according to my requirement

Comment: have you find this css file in Ced_CsMarketplace module? If not then you can not override css file, it's autogenerated file. You need to override related .less file in theme

Comment: as per magento standards , do not put any file in pub/static folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edit css in your current theme***

```
/app/design/frontend/Ced/ced_2k18/web/css/seller_new.css
```

***change css in this file according to Your requirement***

***create .htaccess***

***add file in pub/static/.htaccess***

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

# To avoid situation when web server automatically adds extension to path
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    ## you can put here your pub/static folder path relative to web root
    #RewriteBase /magento/pub/static/

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    RewriteRule ^version.+?/(.+)$ $1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* ../static.php?resource=$0 [L]
    # Detects if moxieplayer request with uri params and redirects to uri without params
    <Files moxieplayer.swf>
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
     </Files>
</IfModule>

############################################
## setting MIME types

# JavaScript
AddType application/javascript js jsonp
AddType application/json json

# HTML

AddType text/html html

# CSS
AddType text/css css

# Images and icons
AddType image/x-icon ico
AddType image/gif gif
AddType image/png png
AddType image/jpeg jpg
AddType image/jpeg jpeg

# SVG
AddType image/svg+xml svg

# Fonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf ttf
AddType application/x-font-otf otf
AddType application/x-font-woff woff
AddType application/font-woff2 woff2

# Flash
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash swf

# Archives and exports
AddType application/zip gzip
AddType application/x-gzip gz gzip
AddType application/x-bzip2 bz2
AddType text/csv csv
AddType application/xml xml

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    <FilesMatch .*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|json)$>
        Header append Cache-Control public
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch .*\.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$>
        Header append Cache-Control no-store
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresActive On

    # Data
    <FilesMatch \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 0 seconds"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/csv "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/zip "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-bzip2 "access plus 0 seconds"

    # CSS, JavaScript, html
    <FilesMatch \.(css|js|html|json)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 1 year"

    # Favicon, images, flash
    <FilesMatch \.(ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|swf|svg)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"

    # Fonts
    <FilesMatch \.(eot|ttf|otf|svg|woff|woff2)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>
```

***Then After run command (ssh)***

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: is anything wrong?

Comment: My site looses its layout. See staging.ihouzit.com

Comment: @Nafisa Did you run command ?

Comment: Yes .... i did rm -rf pub/static. Does that creates problem?

Comment: just  after run command i mention in answer

Comment: @Nafisa see updated answer

Comment: i ran all the commands

Comment: @Nafisa did you created .htaccess file in pub/static/ ?

Comment: No. that not there. Can i copy it from my production server?

Comment: yes create this file and then after run command

Comment: php bin/magento setup:upgrade,
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f,
php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: @Nafisa don't panic just follow my answer

Comment: Done everything still same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99331/discussion-between-nafisa-and-savan-patel).

Comment: working. Thanks @SavanPatel

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy your css file from the module into the current theme

copy `ced_vpanel.css` from :

```
app/code/Ced/CsMarketplace/view/frontend/web/css/ced/csmarketplace/ced_vpanel.css
```

into :

```
app/design/frontend/YourThemehere/themenamehere/Ced_CsMarketplace/web/css/ced/csmarketplace/ced_vpanel.css
```

**Note:** don't forget to :

```
clean the cache

clean var/view_preprocessed content

clean pub/static content

deploy the static content = php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: @Prince . Sorry the path is /pub/static/frontend/Ced/ced_2k18/en_US/css/seller_new.css. and there is no seller_new.css in app/code/Ced folder. It is present in /app/design/frontend/Ced/ced_2k18/web/css/seller_new.css.

Comment: So if the path is : `/app/design/frontend/Ced/ced_2k18/web/css/seller_new.css` this mean that your css is in your current theme and you have to update it (add your css inside) without problem, just you need the deploy the static content to see you update in your Magento (to generate you update in `pub/static`)

Comment: @Prince My site looses its layout. See https://staging.ihouzit.com/

Comment: @Nafisa what did you do ?

Comment: @Prince Did changes in file and followed your command. did rm -rf pub/static also

Comment: @Nafisa `rm -R pub/static/*` and not `rm -R pub/static` I told CONTENT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99327/discussion-between-nafisa-and-pinc).